# Ugly rendering of curve with ParametricPlot3D and NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics3d, parametric-functions, output

I frequently have this rendering problem when I plot a complicated curve with ParametricPlot3D, found by solving a differential equation with NDSolve :

[image: Ugly curve]

The curve should be more "regular" (it is showing the motion of a charged particle around some magnetic field lines).  I've indicated in red the typical artifacts I'm getting.  And yet, in ParametricPlot3D, I'm using options like these :

```
PlotPoints -> 1000,
MaxRecursion -> 7,
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
```

In NDSolve, I'm using these options :

```
Method -> ExplicitRungeKutta,
PrecisionGoal -> 7,
MaxSteps -> 1000000,
```

So what may be wrong ?  How can I get a better graphical output of the curve, without the glitches and straight line artifacts shown on the picture above ?

**EDIT :**  You can see some of the artifacts I'm describing if you play a bit with the code from this demonstration (you need to lower the "velocity" and "distance", using the Manipulate sliders.) :  http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DipoleFieldsAreComplicated/

My own code is more complicated than this demo (this is why I don't provide a MWE example here), but the artifacts are the same.

Comment: This is an ill-posed question. You do not provide sufficient code to reproduce the problem. You do not even clearly state what you don't like about the plot. Saying that the curves are ugly is not sufficient -- "ugly" is not a technical term.

Comment: I think the picture says it all.  By "ugly", I mean an output that isn't "right".  See the straigth line artifacts on the picture above.

Comment: How can I, or anybody else, know the lines are artifacts when you don't post the code you used to generate the image?

Comment: Because it's obvious if you examine the picture !  See the straight lines there ?  They shouldn't be there.  The curve is "regular" (rotation around some magntic field lines).  Should I change that picture by adding some red arrows to point to the artifacts ?

Comment: You seem to think people reading your post have ESP and know everything about your problem that you do. That is not the case. I could not tell your plot was "The curve is 'regular' (rotation around some magntice field lines)" just by looking at it. It is your responsibility to ask a clear and complete question.

Comment: I've edited the question and changed the picture.  Is it clearer now ?

Comment: No, I'm afraid it's not.  Everyone, including m_goldberg, saw the straight segments.  Maybe it's because of `NDSolve`.  Maybe you're using `ParametricPlot3D` wrong -- it looks like a typical `PlotPoints` problem.  Problems with code normally require the code for folks to be able to answer.  Maybe it's a V7 problem, in which case, there are few users here who can help.  (You shouldn't tag it [tag:version-7] unless you know the problem is specific to that version and not to others.)

Comment: I would suggest that you increase PlotPoints even more. Try reducing PrecisionGoal and MaxSteps to get a reasonable computation time for now, and make PlotPoints 2000. Also, I am sorry for the negative comments here.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I'm pretty sure NDSolve is doing it's job right.  My problem is just a graphical output one (I may be wrong).

Comment: @thedude, I always was "afraid" in rising the PlotPoints above 1000.  Sometimes, Mathematica give me a warning message saying that 1000 in PlotPoints is very high and may impact performances.

Comment: If you turn down `MaxRecursion` to like 0 or 1 then it should be safe to increase `PlotPoints` beyond 1000.

Comment: Just doing `Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 1}]]` with a very large `k` should be an MWE, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Rahul, nope, using your simple function doesn't give any artifatcs, even with k -> 1000.  I think the graphics should be 3D.

Comment: @MichaelE2, how do you use the **ListLinePlot** ?  I don't know this command.

Comment: Or directly use graphics: `ifn = Interpolation@Table[{t, {t , 10 Sin[t], 10 Cos[t]}}, {t, 0, 100, 0.1}]; Graphics3D[Line@ifn[Flatten[ifn["Coordinates"]]]]`

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't provided any code, I wrote one for a particle in magnetic field to replicate the error:

```
Module[{T = 10^-2, pts = 50, k = 10^4},
 x = r[t].{1, 0, 0}; y = r[t].{0, 1, 0}; z = r[t].{0, 0, 1};
 B1[x_, y_, z_] = x {1, 1, 0};
 p = NDSolve[
   {-r''[t] == k Cross[r'[t], B1[x, y, z]], r[0] == {2, 1, -1}, 
    r'[0] == {0, 10^3, 0}}, r[t], {t, 0, T}, PrecisionGoal -> 5
   ];
 ParametricPlot3D[
  r[t] /. p, {t, 0, T}, PlotPoints -> pts, PlotStyle -> Green, 
  Background -> Black, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False
  ]
 ]
```

With `pts = 50`,

[image]

With `pts = 500`,

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Regarding your question about `MaxRecursion`, you can see that increasing `rec` does not help if `PlotPoints` is set low enough:

```
Do[
 Module[{T = 0.3 10^-2, pts = 20, k = 10^4}, 
x = r[t].{1, 0, 0}; y = r[t].{0, 1, 0}; z = r[t].{0, 0, 1};
B1[x_, y_, z_] = x {1, 1, 0};
p = NDSolve[{-r''[t] == k Cross[r'[t], B1[x, y, z]], 
    r[0] == {2, 1, -1}, r'[0] == {0, 10^3, 0}}, r[t], {t, 0, T}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 5];
Print@ParametricPlot3D[r[t] /. p, {t, 0, T}, PlotPoints -> pts, 
    MaxRecursion -> rec, PlotStyle -> Lighter@Purple, Background -> Black, 
    PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
    ImageSize -> 1000]],
 {rec, 0, 15}
]
```

When `rec=3`,

[image]

When `rec=15`,

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of artifacts I was talking about.  But now, I'm not sure anymore of the meaning of **PlotPoints**.  And what about **MaxRecursion** ?  And by the way, why the **Module**, instead of declaring each parameter separately ?  What are the advantages of Module ?

Comment: Module has no advantage here; I just like to use it.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Removing **MaxRecursion** and using **PlotPoints -> ControlActive[200, 5000]** appears to solve my issue (5000 points ?).  Now I'm not sure when I should add **MaxRecursion** to my codes.  I believed it was necessary when the curve has lots of tiny parts, like in the example above (path in a magnetic field).